# Datastage performance statistics

Tags: performance, statistics, datastage

we have datastage jobs on production that recently stop showing performance statistics. We already made sure that we have enough memory for the logs and we didn't see any errors in jobmon.log and tried restarting it a couple of times. APT_JOB_MON is set to false. And localhost is set at etc/host. Asking for any idea what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the statistics on the link in the Datastage Designer - if nothing at all is shown make sure the statistics are switched on in the GUI (there is a button for that or a menu entry)

Also check this help document for [job monitor problems](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/diagnosing-datastage-job-monitor-problems) by IBM